Pug template not working with nuxt variables
I am trying to run a simple pug for loop inside of my nuxt app.
I installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pug-loader by running the commands, and the syntax seems to work:
<template lang="pug">
  if (10 / 2) == 5
    p Hello world!
</template>

This shows hello world correctly, so does a for loop like
<template lang="pug">
  for item in ["1", "2", "3"]
    p #{item}
</template>

But whenever I try and use a variable from my script It throws an error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
<template lang="pug">
  for item in pages // error triggers here
    p #{item}
</template>

<script>
let pages = ["1", "2", "3"]
</script>

<style>
</style>

What am I doing wrong?

It doesn't relates to Pug.

<script>
let pages = ["1", "2", "3"]
</script>


<script> and <script setup> are different, see API Styles. The top-level variables in <script> won't be exposed to <template>.
You can simply change <script> to <script setup>, or:
<script>
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    let pages = ["1", "2", "3"]
    return { pages }
  }
})
</script>

Or using Options API:
<script>
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return { pages: ["1", "2", "3"] }
  }
})
</script>


That doesn't seem to work strangely, I tried all of your methods but its still the same error

@mrolland Please provide a [mre] using StackBlitz or CodeSandbox
